# I want to filter ages older than 30 years in this array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, filter

```
const people = [
    {firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'Hughes', DOB: '07/07/1978', department: 'Development', salary: '45000'},
    {firstName: 'Terri', lastName: 'Bishop', DOB: '07/04/1989', department: 'Development', salary: '35000'},
    {firstName: 'Jar', lastName: 'Burke', DOB: '11/01/1985', department: 'Marketing', salary: '38000'},
    {firstName: 'Julio', lastName: 'Miller', DOB: '12/02/1991', department: 'Sales', salary: '40000'},
    {firstName: 'Chester', lastName: 'Flores', DOB: '15/03/1988', department: 'Development', salary: '41000'},
    {firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'Marshall', DOB: '22/09/1980', department: 'Sales', salary: '32000'},
    {firstName: 'Gabriella', lastName: 'Steward', DOB: '26/08/1994', department: 'Marketing', salary: '46000'},
    {firstName: 'Ava', lastName: 'Pena', DOB: '02/11/1986', department: 'Office Management', salary: '38000'},
]
```

Here is my code:

```
const olderThan30 = people.filter(age => Number(new Date().getFullYear()) - Number(age.DOB) > 30 )

console.log(olderThan30)
```

Comment: ```Number(new Date().getFullYear())``` --> here you'll get the current year. You must debug your code. Do a console.log with at least one item from your calculation and your bool test.

Answer (score 1):

you need add Date to check the year for your DOB string to verify the year

```js
const people = [
    {firstName: 'Sam', lastName: 'Hughes', DOB: '07/07/1978', department: 'Development', salary: '45000'},
    {firstName: 'Terri', lastName: 'Bishop', DOB: '07/04/1989', department: 'Development', salary: '35000'},
    {firstName: 'Jar', lastName: 'Burke', DOB: '11/01/1985', department: 'Marketing', salary: '38000'},
    {firstName: 'Julio', lastName: 'Miller', DOB: '12/02/1991', department: 'Sales', salary: '40000'},
    {firstName: 'Chester', lastName: 'Flores', DOB: '15/03/1988', department: 'Development', salary: '41000'},
    {firstName: 'Madison', lastName: 'Marshall', DOB: '22/09/1980', department: 'Sales', salary: '32000'},
    {firstName: 'Gabriella', lastName: 'Steward', DOB: '26/08/1994', department: 'Marketing', salary: '46000'},
    {firstName: 'Ava', lastName: 'Pena', DOB: '02/11/1986', department: 'Office Management', salary: '38000'},
];

const olderThan30 = people.filter(age => Number(new Date().getFullYear()) - Number(new Date(age.DOB).getFullYear()) > 30 );

console.log(olderThan30);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I ain't wrong, you have an error on this line:

```
const olderThan30 = people.filter(age => Number(new Date().getFullYear()) - Number(age.DOB) > 30 )
```

You do a `new Date()` to use it as the actual age, but then you are doing `Number(age.DOB)`

You could parse the date of the object age to a `Date` too, and then get both the years and and then compare them to see if they are bigger than 30

Comment: The DOB, date of birth day is an string as you showed us in the people. If you use this string to parse it with the object date and you have the NOW object date, it's way easier to compare both dates

Answer (score 0):

You can get accurate results by the following...

```
const olderThan30 = people.filter(age => (new Date() - new Date(age.DOB) ) > (new Date('1/1/2030') - new Date('1/1/2000') ))
```

Comment: okay, but is there no need to implement .getFullYear() since the DOB has year as the format